# passing data from child to parent and parent to dispatch action creators

Tags: reactjs, redux

i have a child component called "subjects", where i call a function calculateSubjects

```
    calculateSubjects(){
      // doing some calculation
     this.props.calculatedValueOfSubjects(data)
   }
```

now i have a parent component "class" where i call the child component "subjects" as

```
<Subjects calculatedValueOfSubjects= {(data) =>this.props.onCalculatedValueOfSubjects(data)} />

// map dispatch to props
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        onCalculatedValueOfSubjects: (data) => dispatch(actions.changeCalculatedValue(data))
      }
    }
```

so whenever i pass the data from child to parent and from parent to dispatch action its an infinite loop when i make a console.log in action creators and reducers. so whats the best method to pass data from child to parent and from parent to action creators using dispatch

Comment: how are you calling `calculateSubjects`

Comment: in componentDidUpdate

Comment: Can you show the implementation

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function at the time of calling from child component.

calculateSubjects=()=>{}